# Slick-Slider: Show hide slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js

How can you show/ hide slides based on a condition 
Example: A button outside the slider, which shows/hides (toogles) the second slide.

I found the **Add & Remove** function in the documention ( http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ), but this removes the complete slide and I can't get it anymore.

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked this too. However the above example doesnt have any effect over the slider's dot navigation.

What you are really looking for is the filtering method.

`slickFilter`

If you look up to slickFilter here on this link you'd find an example and the doc.

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Update: here is a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fonsekaean/1r77fc5c/1/

Cheers

Comment: Can you make an example with it, then I change the accepted anser

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that show/ hidding slides already works pretty nice with slick slider. The following example worked for me :)

```js
    $(function () {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });

      $('[data-js-show-hide-slide-btn]').click(function () {
        $('[data-js-hidesample]').toggle('slow');
      });
    });
```

```css
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 25px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

      .slick-slide img {
        width: 100%;
      }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }

    .hidde-sldie img {
      border: 5px solid red;
    }

    .show-hide-slide-btn {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>



  <button class="show-hide-slide-btn" data-js-show-hide-slide-btn>
    Show hide Slide 2
  </button>

  <section class="regular slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="hidde-sldie" data-js-hidesample style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
  </section>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m2pyygx6/